# Displaying real time in a text input box

Tags: r, date, time, shiny

I have a text input box that uses Sys.time() as its value, however as normal time passes it stays static, I've been trying to refresh the time to display a new value, but insofar the only way I've been able to update the time is via restarting the app.

I've tried using textoutput() and the invalidate later() function, however this only displays the current time that "ticks" so to speak but still requires user input, which is redundant since the whole point is to have them not enter the time. This input and a few others eventually gets uploaded into a google sheet via the googlesheets package.

this is my current code:

```
Stime <- as.character(format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M", "EST"))

textInput(
          inputId = "Time",
          label = "Today's Time",
          value = Stime)
```

[what it looks like now (via imgur) except it is static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uXFu.jpg)

The only thing I'm trying to do is literally increment the time! Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From the R Shiny website:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/current-time.html

```
options(digits.secs = 3) # Include milliseconds in time display

function(input, output, session) {

  output$currentTime <- renderText({
    # invalidateLater causes this output to automatically
    # become invalidated when input$interval milliseconds
    # have elapsed
    invalidateLater(as.integer(input$interval), session)

    format(Sys.time())
  })
}
```

Comment: I implemented that earlier, but I did just try it again, and now I'm getting the error: `Error in thisFunc() : could not find function "thisFunc"` and now the app won't even run even with it commented out, I've searched the error and the only thing I can find right now is restarting the session.

Comment: I cannot tell you what's going on without the code that caused the error. Given the name of your function it looks like you've tried to change things. Does it work if you copy the exact code?

Comment: I copied it exactly, changing only the input ID's, I'm still getting the previously stated error, I currently have it commented out however as enabling it will cause the app to "crash" so to speak. I would like clarify however, that while it states real time it doesn't display it inside the actual input box as the value as I intended. As of now I have the time listed inside the box however it doesn't increment as I would like it to.

Answer (score 0):

I have amended the `shiny` example slightly from http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/current-time.html to help display time within a `textInput` box, as requested:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shiny::fluidPage(shiny::uiOutput("ui"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {  
  output$ui <- shiny::renderUI({
    invalidateLater(1000, session)
    shiny::textInput(
      inputId = "time",
      label = "Today's Time",
      value = as.character(format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M", "EST"))
    )
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: my apologies for the SUPER late reply, I've adjusted what Ive written to your example and it only updates with a page or app manual refresh. I'm still working on it now.

Comment: @SebastianGoslin On my side, when I test it, it does not need a refresh to update.